# Extract cells from image

Tags: image-processing

How can I extract each cell (= patch that is not crossed by the contour) from an image such as

[image]

I thought `SelectComponents` (e.g. `SelectComponents[img, #Width > 1 &]`) could do it but I did not manage. I need to keep track of the position of the cell also, so the output could be a few hundreds images of the same size as the original image, with white everywhere except for the cells.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a start:

```
img = ColorConvert[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SREb.png"], "Grayscale"];
MorphologicalComponents[Binarize[img, .7]] // Colorize
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want some insight, why this works, then look at the binary image. You'll see that each white patch is surrounded by a black line.